# How do you enable stack smashing protection for an iOS app built with Xamarin?

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

If I'm not mistaken, if you want to enable stack smashing protection in an iOS app built with XCode, you need to specify the `–fstack-protector-all` compiler flag. Is there some analogous action in Xamarin that does this? Is it done by default?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not supported.

Managed languages in general come with built-in "arrays bounds checking", so the major use for this tool is not very useful with C# code.

There are scenarios where this is needed, for example, if you invoke native code using P/Invoke.   So those scenarios would not be covered.

Comment: Ah, yes. It was a silly question, in retrospect. Thanks.

Comment: @PJones Not silly at all and in contrast a very good question!

Comment: @miguel.de.icaza How about for React Native? Does this mean, I have to set the flag manually?